# Como manter um projeto em 2 repositórios?

Tags: git

Eu tenho um projeto e queria manter ele no Bitbucket/Gitlab e no GitHub ao mesmo tempo. Isso é possível?

Eu preciso que eles trabalhem simultaneamente de forma que se eu quiser fazer um `push` apenas no Bitbucket eu consiga.

Comment: Na sua máquina vai ter seus códigos e seu repositório local. Basta adicionar quantos `remote` você precisar. Nos meus projetos eu sempre tenho um `remote origin`  e um `remote deploy`. Assim quando eu quero atualizar o repositório eu uso `git push origin master` quando quero atualizar o site uso `git push deploy master`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As outras respostas sugerem criar um *remote* para cada repositório remoto (ex: um para o GitHub, outro para o Bitbucket), e em seguida fazer `push` para cada um deles.

É uma solução perfeitamente válida, mas também é possível, com apenas um `push`, atualizar todos os repositórios remotos.

---

Para começar, vamos assumir que fiz um `git clone url.github` e o projeto já está na minha máquina. Quando é feito um `clone`, [por padrão ele já cria um `remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_description) chamado *origin*, como podemos ver com o comando `git remote`. Ex:

```bash
$ git remote -v
origin url.github (fetch)
origin url.github (push)
```

Podemos ver que a URL para `fetch` e `push` são as mesmas, indicando que estas serão as URLs usadas para os respectivos comandos.

Mas o `git remote` também possui [opções](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem) que permitem adicionar várias URLs diferentes para `push`. Se quiser, você pode fazer tudo isso no próprio `origin`, mas como este é um *remote* meio que "padrão" (que muitos usam sem pensar quando fazem *copy-paste* de comandos para resolver seus problemas, e qualquer configuração diferente nele pode atrapalhar mais do que ajudar), eu prefiro criar outro *remote* separado para isso (mas nada impede que você faça o procedimento abaixo no *origin*).

Então primeiro vamos criar um novo *remote*, com o *criativo* nome de "**all**" (já que ele vai concentrar *todos* os repositórios remotos):

```bash
# cria um remote chamado "all", apontando para a URL do GitHub
$ git remote add all url.github

# mostra os remotes atuais
$ git remote -v
all url.github (fetch)
all url.github (push)
origin url.github (fetch)
origin url.github (push)
```

Como podemos ver, tanto o **all** quanto o **origin** apontam para a mesma URL. Mas agora vamos configurar o **all** para ter várias URLs de `push` diferentes.

Para isso, usamos o comando [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emset-urlem), usando as opções `--add` (para adicionar uma nova URL) e `--push` (para indicar que estou adicionando uma URL de `push`), além do nome do *remote* (no caso, **all**) e por fim a URL:

```bash
$ git remote set-url --add --push all url.bitbucket
$ git remote -v
all url.github (fetch)
all url.bitbucket (push)
origin url.github (fetch)
origin url.github (push)
```

Repare que agora a URL de `push` foi substituída pela URL do Bitbucket. Isso quer dizer que se eu fizer um `push` para o **all**, ele será enviado somente para o Bitbucket:

```bash
$ git push all master 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 216 bytes | 216.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To url.bitbucket
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Pode parecer estranho que o `--add` sobrescreveu a URL padrão, mas este é o comportamento "esperado" para a primeira URL adicionada, conforme descrito [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145) (veja o comentário no "UPDATE 2"). Mas tudo bem, basta adicionar novamente a URL do GitHub, com o mesmo comando:

```bash
$ git remote set-url --add --push all url.github

$ git remote -v
all url.github (fetch)
all url.bitbucket (push)
all url.github (push)
origin url.github (fetch)
origin url.github (push)
```

Repare que agora o *remote* **all** possui duas URLs de `push`: uma do GitHub e outra do Bitbucket. Isso quer dizer que, quando for feito um `push`, ele será enviado para ambos de uma só vez:

```bash
# fazer push do branch master para o remote "all"
$ git push all master 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 255 bytes | 255.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To url.bitbucket
   3f5d6dc..78ac9a1  master -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 255 bytes | 255.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To url.github
   3f5d6dc..78ac9a1  master -> master
```

Repare que foi feito o `push` tanto para o Bitbucket quanto para o GitHub.

---

Esta opção permite que você adicione quantos repositórios remotos forem necessários. Por exemplo, eu poderia adicionar um repositório no Gitlab:

```bash
$ git remote set-url --add --push all url.gitlab

$ git remote -v
all url.github (fetch)
all url.bitbucket (push)
all url.github (push)
all url.gitlab (push)
origin url.github (fetch)
origin url.github (push)
```

Veja que agora há 3 URLs de `push` (Bitbucket, GitHub e Gitlab). Ao fazer o `push`:

```bash
$ git push all master
Everything up-to-date
Everything up-to-date
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 439 bytes | 439.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To url.gitlab
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Por duas vezes apareceu a mensagem *"Everything up-to-date"*, indicando que dois repositórios remotos já estavam atualizados, e por fim, é mostrado o `push` para o GitLab. Se quiser saber quais os repositórios já estavam atualizados, você pode usar a opção `-v`:

```bash
$ git push -v all master
Pushing to url.bitbucket
To url.bitbucket
 = [up to date]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/all/master'
Everything up-to-date
Pushing to url.github
To url.github
 = [up to date]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/all/master'
Everything up-to-date
Pushing to url.gitlab
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 256 bytes | 256.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To url.gitlab
   78ac9a1..95f90db  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/all/master'
```

Neste caso, é mostrada a URL que está sendo feito o `push`, e a mensagem **"Everything up-to-date"** é mostrada para os que já estão atualizados.

---

Se quiser, você pode fazer tudo isso no *origin*, só precisa lembrar que todo `push` será feito em todos os repositórios remotos.

Comment: E se eu tiver o mesmo projeto em duas contas github com usernames e e-mail diferentes? Tentei seguir sua explicação que por sinal é fantástica mas que para contas github diferentes não funcionou. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @CleberNandi Eu vi a [sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447873/112052) sobre o assunto, mas não a respondi porque realmente não sei como fazer (nunca precisei usar 2 contas diferentes e não faço ideia de como seria a melhor maneira)

Comment: Obrigado, sigo pesquisando e tentando encontrar melhor forma.

Answer (score 12):

Dentro do repositório local do seu projeto, adicione os repositórios externos utilizando o comando `git remote`

```
git remote add github https://github.com/usuario/repositorio

git remote add bitbucket https://bitbucket.com/usuario/repositorio
```

Após um eventual commit, você pode realizar um push especificando qual repositório vai receber as atualizações.

```
git push gibhub master
```

ou

```
git push bitbucket master
```

[Trabalhando com repositório remoto](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Answer (score 10):

Você pode configurar quantos *remotes* você precisar, e quando for dar um push para um repositório basta escolher qual dos *remotes* você quer dar o push.

Ex.:

#### Listar repositórios remotos configurados:

```bsh
git remote -v
# origin    git@gitlab.com:meus-projetos/projeto-joinha.git (fetch)
# origin    git@gitlab.com:meus-projetos/projeto-joinha.git (push)
```

#### Adicionar novo repositório remoto:

```
git remote add deploy usuario@meuservidor.com.br:/srv/git/meu-repositorio.git
```

Na documentação do [`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emaddem) explica a sintaxe do comando:

```
git remote add nome-do-remote usuario@servidor.com:/caminho/do/repositorio
```

#### Checar se o repositório foi adicionado

```bsh
git remote -v
# deploy    usuario@meuservidor.com.br:/srv/git/meu-repositorio.git (fetch)
# deploy    usuario@meuservidor.com.br:/srv/git/meu-repositorio (push)
# origin    git@gitlab.com:meus-projetos/projeto-joinha.git (fetch)
# origin    git@gitlab.com:meus-projetos/projeto-joinha.git (push)
```

Parece OK, agora é só escolher pra qual remote e branch você vai fazer o seu push ou pull:

```bsh
git push origin master
# ou
git push deploy master
```

Comment: Me tira uma dúvida jovem, imagina que eu já tenho um projeto do GitHub rodando direitinho etc, Tem como eu dar um git remote add origin para um repositório no GitLab? Ai eu posso ficar dando git push origin github ou git push origin github conforme eu queira ?

Comment: Você só precisa adicionar o remote com o nome que você quiser...
Se você já tem o projeto no GitHub e já tá com o remote configurado para ele (provavelmente o `origin`) basta adicionar o remoto do GitLab.

Comment: Cria um repositório em branco no GitLab e depois clica em "Clone", vai mostrar algo [como isso](https://imgur.com/UaRzoTy) que são os caminhos para o repositório remote. Aí é só fazer `git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:fernandosavio/teste.git` que o repositório estará configurado

Comment: Tendi jovem, é bom saber :)

Comment: Agora vi que era tu Hugo! :D Depois de fazer os passos acima é só escolher pra onde dar o push. Só um detalhe importante `git push remote branch`, então no teu primeiro comentário seria `git push github master` ao invés de `git push origin github`

Comment: Saquei, to aprendendo Git de leve, só o basicão mesmo para subir um GitPage rss Tirando o fato que outro dia dei um Add no meu desktop inteiro, até agora está de boa de entender as coisas! []´s

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer o push em uma branch específica e não a master?

Comment: Sei que já não é mais necessário mas vou deixar comentado aqui para futuros visitantes. Você pode especificar as branches de origem e de destino usando `:`.. Por exemplo: `git push meu-remote homolog:master` faria o push da branch local `homolog` para a branh `master` do remote `meu-remote`.

Answer (score 0):

Para os demais que ainda podem procurar.

Eu fiz dessa maneira:

1 - Após clonar ou inicializar um repositório, vai criar uma pasta chamada de:

.git

2 - dentro da pasta .git vai ter um arquivo chamado:

config

3 - Abra o arquivo config com bloco de notas e dentro dele terá isso:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://seunome-seunome@bitbucket.org/seunome-seunome/repositorioQueCriei.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

4 - basta acrescentar a url de um novo repositório dentro do [remote "origin"] que ficaria dessa forma:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://seunome-seunome@bitbucket.org/seunome-seunome/repositorioQueCriei.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://github.com/seunome/repositorioqueCrieinogithub.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Espero que tenho ajudado.